# Python requests module using TLSv1.2 even though I am specifying TLSv1.1

Tags: python, python-requests, tls1.2

Our payment processing partner can only support TLSv1.1 for the time being. Switching processors is not an option right now.

In Python 2.7.10, I have a script which requests a GET from my dev web server, but at runtime it uses TLSv1.2 instead of TLSv1.1 like I am telling it to.

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl


class MyAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1,
        )
        print("poolmanager set")


def do_it():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
        url = 'https://my.server.com/api/3.0/order/?page=1&limit=10'
        response = requests.get(url, verify=True)
        print("status code: %r" % response.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print do_it()
```

The output is:

```
poolmanager set
status code: 200
```

My nginx access log, however, says that the protocol used was TLSv1.2:

```
127.0.0.1 - [15/Dec/2015:13:38:19 -0600] TLSv1.2/ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET /api/3.0/order/?page=1&limit=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 176 "-" "python-requests/2.9.0"
```

I have poured over the skint documentation around implementing and mounting HTTPAdapters with the requests library, and I cannot find anything that would indicate why my client is speaking TLSv1.2 instead of TLSv1.1 like I am telling it to.

Comment: I think ssl_verson is incorrect. Should be ssl_version?

Comment: @rfkortekaas Thanks for catching that. I thought for sure that would be it, but correcting that typo made no difference.  I am currently seeing some success using straight urllib2, but still having to work through issues.  I will update the question now.

Comment: You also need s.get to use the session object with the HTTPadapter

Comment: @rfkortekaas is right - you're setting up a session and mounting the adapter, but then *you're not using the session* (which is why the typo in the keyword argument didn't trigger an error, your adapter was never being used).

Comment: Thank you very much guys. It's not clear from the python-requests documentation how to use Session's get() method. I would kill for java-style API docs in this case. This documentation shows the get method being called like this:  's.get(url)'. Do I replace my call to requests.get() with s.get()? I tried that and it predictably failed.

Comment: I was completely wrong!!! s.get() worked perfectly!! I had changed my test script to speak SSL3 to force a failure from the web server. This is the answer!!  What is best etiquette-wise? Should I answer my own question and give you guys credit, or let one of you provide an answer?

Comment: @Rjak yes, a requests `Session` object is just a drop-in replacement for the API on the `requests` module. Instead of `requests.post()` you do `s.post()` etc.

Comment: It really was @rfkortekaas that pointed out the solution, so I certainly don't deserve any credit ;-) Self-answering and giving credit to him would be totally fine IMHO, but you could also give him some time to write up his own answer. As far as I know, you can also change the accepted answer at a later point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use s.get (the Session with the mounted HTTPAdapter) instead of requests.get.

Comment: s.get() acts as a drop-in replacement for requests.get() in this context. Same arguments and return type.

Comment: Can you post your full code example to get this working?